# UART baudrate steps

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, arm, uart

I'm trying to connect 2 devices to each other based on the UART peripheral. First one support up to 1.875 Mb/s & the other one up to 1228.8 KBd. Both work correctly on the 115200 but I need more transfer speed. I know below 115200 usual baud rate steps are 9600, 19200, 38400 & etc. But I don't have any idea about steps above 115200? Also I think this steps are dependent on the clock sources of device (e.g. external crystal) & if there will be not harmony between CLK & Baud rate, accuracy will be decreased. Is there any online tools for calculating baud rate & accuracy dependent on clock pulse? How can I calculate maximum baud rate which these devices are able to interconnect? WBR.

**EDIT:**

MCU is lpc812 & there are not any information about baud rate steps in datasheet,nor in the user manual. The only thing there are is:

**Maximum bit rates of 1.875 Mbit/s in asynchronous mode and 10 Mbit/s in
synchronous mode for USART functions connected to all digital pins except PIO0_10 and PIO0_11.**

Comment: Have you examined the datasheets yet?

Comment: It will be device dependent. You need to look at the datasheets or reference manuals. There is nothing we can help with, since we don't even know what the devices are.

Comment: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/D37754FFA24F7C3F86256706005B9BE7

Comment: The info about the UART and its baudrate generator is cerainly in the datasheet and/or family reference manual. If you control both sides of the communication, there us no reason to stick to the 'common' baudrates, you can choose any rate as long as it is within the device's specs and the same on both sides.

Comment: The [LPC81XM Data Sheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC81XM.pdf) seems to be just a marketing overview; the detailed register maps and useful functional descriptions are in the [User Manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10601.pdf).

Comment: The baud-rate generator in the LPC812 is pretty flexible, but not simple. The description on how to set it up in in the User Manual (http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10601.pdf) in section 15.3.1 on page 188. You just need to select a baud-rate that can also be selected on your other device.

Comment: What is the other device?

Comment: uarts will do vastly more different rates than the handful of common ones.  it is just a clock and a divisor (or set of divisors), you just need to compute the possibilities for each side and find something close enough or the same.